# Vimeo video, progress and disable fast forward

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am working on a site used for mandatory instruction. We have to make sure the student watches the video and doesn't fast forward. I would also like to remember the progress the student made in the video in case they need to leave then return later to complete watching.

I have used this JS to remove the ability to fast forward. I'm just not sure how to get the code to remember the progress, then start at that point if the student returns later.

```
var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
var timeWatched = 0;
player.on("timeupdate", function(data) {
  if (data.seconds - 1 < timeWatched && data.seconds > timeWatched) {
    timeWatched = data.seconds;
  }
});
player.on("seeked", function(data) {
  if (timeWatched < data.seconds) {
    player.setCurrentTime(timeWatched);
  }
});
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the current time in database for future use and then pass to the js whenever user views the video